# How to save a pcolormesh image from matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

super simple question but I've been stuck on it for too long and haven't found anything to help.

Using the following code I generate an image that I can see in spyder, but nevertheless when I call the save function, it saves an empty (all white) image.

```
x,y = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)
z = np.array(zs)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2,8))
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, z.T, cmap='RdYlGn')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

this is what I see in the IDE:

[image]

this is what gets saved:

[image]

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure this question has a duplicate somewhere, but I couldn't find it. Maybe someone else can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the image before showing it. Instead of

```
plt.show()
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

you need

```
plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.show()
```

The reason is that after the plot is shown by `plt.show()` the figure will be  removed from the current pyplot state such that what is saved is a new figure without any content.

However, the figure itself is still present. So if you have a figure handle, you may actually use it to save the figure after it has been shown. The following therefore works:

```
plt.show()
fig.savefig('test.png')
```