# How to save an array as an image

Tags: python, matplotlib

There is a vector which i have done stft transform on it in python and i got an image as output. I am trying to save it in a directory but as it has three parameters(f, t, Zxx), i don't know how to save it. thanks if anyone can help me to save it thanks if anyone can help me to save it. my code is as below

```
#Importing the Libraries-----------------------------------------------------------------------
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import loadmat

#Importing the Data----------------------------------------------------------------------------

train_data = loadmat('D:\\thesis\\new data 
preproceses\\A_train_segmented_onehot\\Data_train_3ch_A_train.mat')
train_data = train_data.get('Data_train_3ch_A_train')

#Defiening the parameters----------------------------------------------------------------------
fs = 10e3
N = 1e5
amp = 2 * np.sqrt(2)

#Calculate STFT---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
f, t, Zxx = signal.stft(train_data[0], fs, nperseg=20)

#Plot Image ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, np.abs(Zxx), vmin=0, vmax=amp, shading='gouraud')
plt.title('STFT Magnitude')
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already a builtin function in maplotlib / pyplot to save the plot as an image, this will be probably easier for your issue:

Before `plt.show()`, use [`savefig` function](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html):

```
plt.savefig('example.png')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. may you explain it as this case? what should be instead of 'example.png'

Comment: I don't really know what to explain, except that this function just does what you need: it saves the plot as a .png file (instead of displaying it on the screen). Of course, you can tweak some options (see the documentation link in the answer). See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45691538/how-to-save-a-pcolormesh-image-from-matplotlib . Do you have a more specific point that is unclear?